# Creating a database-generated menu on every page in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using CodeIgniter and have a menu on the site that needs to read a list of cities from the database. This is simple to do if it's just on one or two pages - I load the model and call a function from the controller, and pass the data into the view.

But if I want it on every page, that means I have to keep copying the same code to every single controller function and pass the data into the view. (Note, I'm using a separate "header" view that contains the menu.)

What's the best way to automatically load some data on every page load and have it available to my view?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create a new root controller class like `MY_Controller`.

You can read how here: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html

Then make all your controllers extend that class.

Add a function in `MY_Controller` like this:

```
function show_view_with_menu($view_name, $data) {
   $menu_data = $this->menu_model->get_menu(); // load your menu data from the db
   $this->load->view('header', $menu_data); // display your header by giving it the menu
   $this->load->view($view_name, $data); // the actual view you wanna load
   $this->load->view('footer'); // footer, if you have one
}
```

Whenever you normally do load a view, instead do this:

```
$this->show_view_with_menu('view_for_this_controller', $data);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is working a treat! I also just realized that it's really useful for *any* situation where I have a header and footer, that way I can just call one function instead of loading header/main/footer in every controller.

Comment: That link has changed to http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/core_classes.html

Comment: I put this MY_Controller in application/core folder and it is extending the CI_Controller. in my application/controllers folder I have a Testing_controller file and it is extending this MY_Controller file. but I cant use without requiring it ore autoloading it. Why is that happen? In the documentation they don't tell us to autoload or require it.

Answer (score 0):

You define your own `Application_Controller`, which extends `CI_Controller`. All of your own controllers then extend your `Application_Controller` rather than the `CI_Controller`.

In the `__construct()` of your `Application_Controller` you'll introduce the code you've been copying and pasting everywhere previously.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was just to create a display class that handles these things.  A simplified version:

```
class Display
{
    public function load_pages($name, $data = array()) {
        $CI =& get_instance();

        // Top and header templates
        $CI->load->view('header.php', $data);

        // Default to loading the one template file
        $CI->load->view($name, $data);

        // Footer template
        $CI->load->view('footer.php');
    }   
}
```

I have it doing fancier stuff, such as setting default values (page title, meta tags) and loading js/css, etc.  It works just like a shortcut to having to copy/paste the regular templates that I load but also allows me to define a custom template setup if I need to, unlike if you have it do so automatically be extending your controller class.

I haven't had the need to but you can also specify different functions within this class to load different sections of the site, such as `load_admin_pages()` or some such.  In my case I handle that just by setting a prefix parameter that gets prepended to the file paths and that's gotten what I need for my current project.