# How did you bind datas to a view in Codeigniter ( likes View Composers in laravel)?

Tags: php, codeigniter

> ```
> If you have data that you want to be bound to a view each time that view is
> rendered,a view composer can help you ...
> ```

This task can be easily archived in laravel, but I am now using Codeigniter, there is no view composers things. What I have done now is, I create a custom view method, just like below

```
public function view($page,$params=null,$return=false)
{
// Every time I invoke this method, $nav will be passed to 'navigation' view.
$nav=[
    'user' =>'Adam'
];

//return the views as view_partials instead of displayed
$view_partials = array(
    'navigation' => $this->obj->load->view('partials/nav',$nav,true),
    'page_content' => $this->obj->load->view($page,$params,true)
);
// load layout with the view_partials which contain bound data.
$this->obj->load->view($this->_layout,$view_partials,$return);
}
```

This method returns views as 'string', it can not works with json or complex page.... Thank you.

Comment: If anyone have the same question, click http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7473739/creating-a-database-generated-menu-on-every-page-in-codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

Ok, lets make this simple

```
$this->load->view(path_to_htmlpage, $bound_data, FALSE);
```

or

```
$this->load->view(path_to_htmlpage, $bound_data); // by default 3rd param is FALSE
```

this will render html page

If you want to get html page as a string, set 3rd parameter to `TRUE`

```
$html_string = $this->load->view(path_to_htmlpage, $bound_data, TRUE);
```

check https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html

Answer (score 0):

```
public function view($page,$params=null,$return=false)
{

$nav['user']='adam';


$data['navigation']= $this->load->view("partials/nav",$nav,true);
$data['page_content'] = $this->load->view($page,$params,true)


$this->load->view('your_page',$data);
}
```

in yor view page ie.your_page you can use variables $navigation and $page_content to display the pages